# fetch daily customer flow data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to fetch daily customer flow from table 'tbl_transaction' using the following query:

```
SELECT DAY(date_time) AS date, SUM(members) AS customers FROM tbl_transaction WHERE MONTH(date_time)='.$mon.' GROUP BY "date_time"
```

But it is generating this dataset which is not grouped according to date:

```
date | customers

11       3
12       2
13       1
14       2
14       3
15       7
16       4
17       3
17       2
17       7
17       2
18       5
18       5
18       4
19       2
```

How to show the dates and no of customers as on particular date.

Comment: ` GROUP BY "date_time" ` to `GROUP BY date_time`

Comment: that also done...but same result

Comment: can u post the table and some data in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: done---

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45ac2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should look like

```
SELECT DAY(date_time) AS date,
SUM(members) AS customers 
FROM tbl_transaction 
WHERE MONTH(date_time)='03' GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
```

Since date_time is in `Y-m-d H:i:s` so doing Group by `date_time` will return all the rows.

Also if you do Group By `date` which is obtained as `DAY(date_time) AS date` yield wrong result.

```
DAY('2014-01-01') = 1
DAY('2014-02-01') = 1
```

So it will sum up the result for days irrespective of actual date.